# creating lists, searching sth which has been given and making combination on prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to make a Prolog program.
Predicate will be like this:

```
name(name, failedCourse, age)
```

Database of the program is:

```
name(george, math, 20).
name(steve, phys, 21).
name(jane, chem, 22).
```

I want to implement the predicate `nameList(A, B)`. `A` means list of names, `B` means number of names on the list. For example:

```
nameList([george, steve],2). returns true
nameList([george, steve],X). returns X=2
nameList(X,2). returns X=[george, steve]; X=[george, jane]; X=[steve, jane]
nameList([martin],1). returns false (because martin is not included database.)
```

I wanted to make a list that includes all names on the database. For that reason I made a `findall`.

```
descend(X,Y,A) :- name(X,Y,A).
descend(X,Y,A) :- name(X,Z,A),descend(Z,Y,A).
findall(director(X),descend(Y,X),Z).
?- findall(B,descend(B,X,Y),A). returns A = [george, steve, jane].
```

But I could not figure it out to use list `A` in predicates :( I cannot search the list for `A` in the `nameList`.

If you help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: To get all the names simply call: `findall(X, name(X, _, _), Xs)`, i.e. no need for `descend` and `director`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you need is a predicate that calculates *combinations* of a given length and of a given list:

```
comb(0, _, []).

comb(N, [X | T], [X | Comb]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    comb(N1, T, Comb).

comb(N, [_ | T], Comb) :-
    N > 0,
    comb(N, T, Comb).
```

Usage:

```
?- comb(2, [a, b, a], Comb).
Comb = [a, b] ;
Comb = [a, a] ;
Comb = [b, a] ;
false.
```

(See more [here](http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/combinatorics.html).)

Now you can just apply this predicate on your data:

```
name(george, math, 20).
name(steve, phys, 21).
name(jane, chem, 22).    

name_list(L, N) :-
    findall(X, name(X, _, _), Xs),
    length(Xs, Len),
    between(0, Len, N),
    comb(N, Xs, L).
```

Usage examples:

```
?- name_list(L, N).
L = [],
N = 0 ;
L = [george],
N = 1 ;
L = [steve],
N = 1 ;
L = [jane],
N = 1 ;
L = [george, steve],
N = 2 ;
L = [george, jane],
N = 2 ;
L = [steve, jane],
N = 2 ;
L = [george, steve, jane],
N = 3 ;
false.

?- name_list([george, steve], N).
N = 2 ;
false.

?- name_list(L, 2).
L = [george, steve] ;
L = [george, jane] ;
L = [steve, jane] ;
false.
```

Comment: thank you. I think I must work on prolog. But I cannot do another thing. If you help me, I would be very happy :))

Comment: @dark If you like the answer vote it up, if you think it answers your question: mark it as the selected answer, if you have another question then create a new post asking it there. This is how Stackoverflow works...

Answer (score 0):

```
name(george, math, 20).
name(steve, phys, 21).
name(jane, chem, 22).

name_list(Name_List,N) :-
        integer(N),
        findall(Name,name(Name,_,_),L),
        combination(L,N,Name_List).
name_list(Name_List,N) :-
        var(N),
        findall(Name,name(Name,_,_),L),
        length(L,Len),
        for(1,N,Len),
        combination(L,N,Name_List).

combination(X,1,[A]) :-
        member(A,X).
combination([A|Y],N,[A|X]) :-
        N > 1,
        M is N - 1,
        combination(Y,M,X).
combination([_|Y],N,A) :-
        N > 1,
        combination(Y,N,A).
```